# sensor and rst_n in cycle of lights

Tags: vhdl, counter, sensors, light

As can be seen in the testbench waveform at second 35 a change in the state of the traffic lights occurs (signal `light_highway (2 downto 0)`).  What I want is that the cycle does not change again until sensor again transitions to a '1` (not shown).

**Testbench**

[image: testbench waveform]

The intended operation is shown in the expected waveform.

**Expected**
[image: expected waveform]

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity semaforo is

    Port ( sensor : in  STD_LOGIC;

           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst_n : in  STD_LOGIC;
           light_highway : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           light_farm : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));

    end semaforo;

    architecture Behavioral of semaforo is

    signal cuenta: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";
    signal aux:std_logic:='0';

    begin 

    flip_flop: process (clk, rst_n)
    variable z:std_logic:='0';

    begin

    if (rst_n='0') then 

    light_highway <="001";
    light_farm <="100";
    aux<='0'; 

    elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then 

    if (sensor='1') then  
        aux<='1';

        z:='1';
        else 

        --z:='0';
        end if;
        if(z='1') then 
        if cuenta=0 then --SEGUND0 3

            light_highway<= "010";

        elsif cuenta=12 then --SEGUNDO 6
        light_highway <="100";
       light_farm <="001";

        elsif cuenta=40 then --SEGUNDO 13
       light_farm <="010";
        light_highway <="100";
        elsif cuenta=52 then --SEGUNDO 16 
        light_highway <="001";
       light_farm <="100";

    end if;

    end if;

    end if; 

    end process;

  contador : process (clk, rst_n)

  begin

    if rst_n = '0' then
      cuenta <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      --if aux = '1' then
        if (sensor='1' or aux='1')and rst_n='1' then 
        if cuenta < 91 then
          cuenta <= cuenta + 1;
        else
          cuenta <= (others => '0');

        end if;  -- count/wrap
      end if;    -- clock enable
    end if;      -- async reset/clock

 end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Without a testbench the problem can't be duplicated, your questions isn't a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What would happen if you deleted variable `z` (which isn't reset) and instead `if sensor = '1' or aux  = '1' then -- if z = '1' then` in process `flip_flop` to operate the signal lights? The problem appears to be a lack of a reset on `z`, which isn't really needed. Note cuenta is run absolute from time 0, while it could be used to count time between light transitions.

Comment: Code is incomplete and not properly indented. Please fix.

Comment: Either resetting `z` or eliminating `z` and using `sensor = '1' or aux = '1'` as an if statement condition in process flip_flop instead of `z = '1'` gives a [waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEVTE.png) that matches the expected output without the change in value on `light_highway` at 35 seconds.